# How can I convert my string extension method into a stored procedure in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using ASP.NET MVC5 with Entity Framework 6, SQL server 2012 and currently after I return my Iqueryable for my data and then call tolist I call my string extension for which applies a users search query. I would like to apply this on the Iqueryable aka sql query itself or obtain similar functionality in another way. Currently a user can search words out of order, they can use  quotation marks to search for an entire set of text in order with spaces. They can also use a wild card if they don't know a certain number or letter.

Here is my string extension

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

namespace casey.Helpers
 {
public static class SearchStringExtension
{
            public static bool Like(this string str, string value)
    {
        List<string> formatedsearch = new List<string>();
        string searchForNext = ("");
        string searchForx = value;
        searchForx = searchForx.ToUpper();
        searchForx = searchForx.Replace("\\", @"\\");
        searchForx = searchForx.Replace("*", @"\*").Replace("+", @"\+").Replace(":", @"\:").Replace("#", @"\#");
        searchForx = searchForx.Replace("(", @"\(").Replace(")", @"\)").Replace("<", @"\<").Replace(">", @"\>");
        searchForx = searchForx.Replace("{", @"\{").Replace("}", @"\}").Replace("[", @"\[").Replace("]", @"\]");
        searchForx = searchForx.Replace("=", @"\=").Replace("-", @"\-").Replace("_", @"_").Replace("%", @"\%");
        searchForx = searchForx.Replace("|", @"\|").Replace("!", @"\!").Replace("^", @"\^").Replace("%", @"\%");
        searchForx = searchForx.Replace(".", @"\.");
        searchForx = searchForx.Replace("?", ".");
        string s = searchForx;

        //find all words with quotes around them
        //example search string equals I "Like" Fish.
        //asigns Like to rgx
        Regex rgx = new Regex("\"(.+?)\"");
        s = "^";


        // add regular and expression with ignore of all charactes before clause to all quoted words and and clause
        //example ^(?.*Like)
        foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(searchForx))
        {
            s += "(?=.*" + match.Value.Trim('"') + ")";
        }

        //example I "Like" Fish. becomes I Fish
        searchForNext = Regex.Replace(searchForx, "\"(.+?)\"", "");

        //this formats regular non quoted part of string
        char[] delimiter1 = new char[] { ' ' };
        formatedsearch = searchForNext.Split(delimiter1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        //example I Fish becomes  ^(?.*Like)(?=.*I)(?=.*Fish)
        foreach (string searchvalue in formatedsearch)
        {
            s += "(?=.*" + searchvalue + ")";
        }

        //this ignores case and ignores endline characters
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(s, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            if (r.IsMatch(str.ToUpper()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What does it have to do with SQL Server at all? Nowhere I see anything related to database.

Comment: it is a string extension method that is used in my where clause for example CarService.GetAllCars().Where(u => u.PartDescription.Like(SearchSample)).OrderByDescending(s => s.SubmittalDate) the Like is my string extension

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use [Full-Text Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

The philosophy behind full-text search is that, when your character data goes beyond a limit (I think it's 1000 length), SQL Server can't search it anymore using `LIKE` operator. Thus, Microsoft introduced Full-Text Search.

It contains almost every aspect of search build inside. For example, it does a lingual search, which means that synonyms would be counted too. Or it's a fuzzy search, which means that only a match won't suffice, and the weight of the keyword in the target text also matters.

However, if you still want to user simple search that you've provided in your string, I'll provide a query for you.

Comment: If you have a link to a good example of using this for a situation like mine I would appreciate it. I have tried adding Full-Text to my db before and using the FreeText extension in sql didn't give me what I was after. I assume I have a bad understanding of how it could be implemented to meet my requirements.